# Button to send text to other application's textbox/chat? Discord in this case

Tags: c#

Im trying to make a little program that when i press a button it sends a message on discord.

I've learned a bit of c# but im all rusty, and dont remember almost anything.

Hope you can help

This does what i want but i cant make it work on Discord.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow")]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lp1, string lp2);

[DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr handle = FindWindow("Notepad", "Untitled - Notepad");
    if (!handle.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        if (SetForegroundWindow(handle))
        {
            SendKeys.Send("Hello World!");
            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Button is irrelevant. Do you ask how to send a message to a Discord server with C#? Or do you want to manipulate the Discord client somehow?

Comment: i want to send a message to discord using c# yes

Comment: You could have a look at the Discord API, specifically the [create message section](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message)